# Topology on union of disjoint sets.

Tags: general-topology

I'm in my first week of introduction to topology course and we've just covered the basics of topological spaces and basis' for a topology. I'm having trouble with the following question:

> Let $X, Y$ be disjoint sets ($X \cap Y = \emptyset)$ and let $(X, \tau_X), (Y, \tau_Y)$ be topological spaces.
> Let $\tau$ be a topology on $X \cup Y$ defined as follows: $A \in \tau$ if $A=U \cup V$ for some $U \in \tau_X$ and $V \in \tau_Y$.
> Can every topology on $X \cup Y$ be determined by a topology on $X$ and a topology on $Y$ in such manner?

To be honest I'm not even sure I understand the question. I think what this means is that I need to check if $\tau$ is some topology on $X \cup Y$, then every $A \in \tau$ can be written as $A = U \cup V$ for some $U, V$ in some topologies $\tau_X, \tau_Y$ on $X,Y$ respectively, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My interpretation of the question:

> Let $X,Y$ be (nonempty) disjoint sets and $\tau$ a topology on $X\sqcup Y$. Is it necessarily true that there exist topologies $\tau_X,\tau_Y$ on $X,Y$ respectively such that $W\in\tau\iff W=U\sqcup V$ for $U\in\tau_X,V\in\tau_Y$?

This is asking, does every topology on $X\sqcup Y$ make it a coproduct of spaces $X$ and $Y$?

My hint to you is to play around with some really basic examples where, say, $X:=\{1\}$ and $Y:=\{2,3\}$, something like that. Can you find a counterexample?

Going a little more abstract, try to prove this: (if you have encountered connectivity before):

> In the situation above, show that if $\tau$ is connected then no such $\tau_X,\tau_Y$ exist

Comment: Thank you! But isn't the question actually that $\tau \subset \tau_x \cup \tau_Y$? Since the definition that was provided was that for every $A \in \tau$ there exist $U \in \tau_x$ and $V \in \tau_Y$ such that $A=U \cup V$. $\tau$ doesn't have to cover all of $\tau_x \cup \tau_Y$, no?

Comment: Obviously we can take $\tau = \{\emptyset, \{2\}, \{1,2,3\}\}$ and it won't equal the union of $\tau_x$ and $\tau_Y$ (since $\{1\}$ has to be there) but we can construct every $A \in \tau$ with unions and intersections of sets in each of them (for some topologies on $X, Y$).

Comment: @YB1998 The original example read: "$A$ is open if $A=U\cup V$..." and they later say "determines": these, together with the well known context of coproduct topology, make me believe they meant it in the sense that $A$ is open *if and only if* $A=U\cup V$ for some $U,V$ open in $X$ and $Y$. This is known as the "disjoint union" topology or coproduct topology. So I infer $\tau=\tau_x\cup\tau_Y$ is intended

Comment: @YB1998 In the same vein as your $\tau = \{\emptyset, \{2\}, \{1,2,3\}\}$ but simpler: let $\tau=\{\varnothing,X\sqcup Y\}.$ For any topologies $\tau_X,\tau_Y$ on $X,Y$ we have $X\in\tau_X$ and $\varnothing\in\tau_Y$ but (if $X,Y\ne\varnothing$) $X\cup\varnothing\notin\tau.$

Comment: @AnneBauval What do you mean? $\tau=\tau_X\cup\tau_Y$?

Comment: @AnneBauval Ah. On reflection, I did not mean a literal union (which is what I wrote). I'll amend that